# C program: generating directories, links get corrupted

Tags: c

I have a really strange problem in my C program, I don't know how to cut my code to the needed but I will try.
So I am generating a bunch of directories and subdirectories of this structure:

AA/  -- and subdirectories : 0/ , 1/, 2/...
same for BB/

And I do it like this:

```
char *my_location = "/Users/example/Documents/";
int total = 2;
int i, j, total_subDir;
char ***file_location;
total_subDir = 100;
file_location = malloc(sizeof(char**)* total);
char *suffix = "AA/"; char *suffix2 = "BB/";

int my_loc_len = strlen(my_location);

for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {

    char *temp;
    file_location[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)* total_subDir);
    temp = malloc(sizeof(char)* (my_loc_len + 4));
    memcpy(temp, my_location, my_loc_len);
    if (i == 0) memcpy(&temp[my_loc_len], suffix, 3);
    else memcpy(&temp[my_loc_len], suffix2, 3);

    temp[my_loc_len + 3] = '\0';
    int temp_length = strlen(temp);
    mkdir(temp, 0777);

    for (j = 0; j < total_subDir; j++) {
        char *subdir_name;

       subdir_name = malloc(sizeof(char)* 20);
        sprintf(subdir_name, "%d", j);
        int digit_num = strlen(subdir_name);

       file_location[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(char) *(temp_length + digit_num + 1 + 1));
        memcpy(file_location[i][j], temp, temp_length);
        memcpy(&file_location[i][j][temp_length], sub_dir_name, digit_num);
        memcpy(&file_location[i][j][temp_length + digit_num], "/", 1);

        file_location[i][j][temp_length + digit_num + 1] = '\0';

        mkdir(file_location[i][j], 0777);
        free(subdir_name);
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

I use this set of links only in one method, where it is just giving the path where to save some files, so like:

```
  void save_information(char **some_info, char *location)
```

where location is one of the subdirectories, so: file_location[i][j]; so I never change the links.

However, sometimes it happens that the links to the directories get corrupted, so I get something like: "/Users/ex1mple/Documents/", and usually just in one link. And when I rerun my program with the same data several times, sometimes there is the corrupted file, sometimes it isn't, and it is not always the same link...

I quess there is no one answer to my problem, I suppose I have some memory write/ problem somewhere, but I cannot reconstruct where it is. I run valgrind over my code and he is also not finding anything. Does someone maybe have any clue how could I retrieve my error, any suggestions?

Comment: Is there some particular reason for using memcpy in string operations?

Comment: That code is really horrible. All those `memcpy` calls make my skin crawl. I'd want to clean that up and use string functions, and then take stock. C is a nasty language to use for this kind of stuff. Can't you use something more suitable. You also should never write `sizeof(char)`. By definition that equals 1.

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan opinion on this code. Some of your `malloc`s are completely redundant. If the array is of fixed length, then just allocate it on the stack. Also, those constant strings. Try to put them all in one place at the beginning of the function. As a matter of fact, just as a "promise to us" that you're not trying to change them (since it's hard to follow them in your code), please `#define` them as macros. If you write a single character into a string, then don't use `memcpy`.

Comment: So what should i write insead of sizeof(char), how to allocate memory for an array of chars instead?

Comment: And what If i change it to string operations, it will not change anything, i avoid them because they do redundant searches for the terminal symbol, going to the whole string, and if i know where it is it is nice to avoid this

Comment: And one more thing, why and how should i define a bunch of strings like macros? I mean like i explained, I have a directory and hundred subdirectories in it, so you suggest I should save every link in a macro?

Answer (score 1):

You could improve your code with proper use of `Macros`, avoid `memcpy`, unnecessary `malloc`, use generic `functions` and introduce `error-checking` for the above task.

The following code does your intended task.

```
#define SUBDIR          100
#define PERMISSION      0777
#define PARENT_PATH     "/Users/example/Documents/"

/* Function to create Directories */
void create_dir (char *file_name, int PERM)
{
    printf("Creating Directory : [%s]\n", file_name);
    if (-1 == mkdir(file_name, PERM)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in mkdir: [%d][%s]\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return;
}
```

---

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        if (1 == argc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <NO_OF_SUBDIR>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (atoi(argv[1]) > 26) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Value should be lesser than 26 (A-Z)\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i, j, suffix = 65;               /* ASCII value for A is 65 */

    /* Filename not to exceed 1024 characters */
    char *temp = malloc (sizeof(char) * 1024);      

    for (i=0; i<atoi(argv[1]); i++)
    {       
        sprintf(temp, "%s/%c/", PARENT_PATH, suffix);           

        /* Creates Directory, ex: For input 1, creates dir A*/
        create_dir(temp, PERMISSION);   
        for (j=0; j<SUBDIR; j++)
        {
            /* Creates Sub-directory ex: /A/0 .. /A/99/ */
            sprintf(temp, "%s/%c/%d", PARENT_PATH, suffix, j);
            create_dir(temp, PERMISSION);
        }
        /* Increments to ASCII of next Alphabet */ 
        suffix++;
    }       
    free(temp);
    return 0;          
}
```

Compilation & Execution:

```
$ gcc -o exe 2.c -Wall -Wextra
$ ./exe 1          /* Creates dir A, with 0-99 sub directories */
$ ./exe 2          /* Creates dir A and B, with 0-99 sub directories in each */
$ ./exe 26         /* Creates dir A to Z,  with 0-99 sub directories in each */
$ ./exe 27
Value should be lesser than 27 (A-Z)
```

Comment: this looks really nice, thank you. Is sprintf the method to use when I have to concatenate more than one string on another?

Comment: `sprintf` will print to a string, so you could employ this for concatenating strings (paths in this case) with `/` separator. Appropriate use of `Macros` and `Function` will reduce your code, making it more readable/understandable and *simple*. Adding error-checking will make your code easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Saurabh Meshram's solution is the preferred one. I still want to show this version only to illustrate to the asker, how his code coud look like just by removing the unnecessary `mallocs` and using string operations instead of `memcpy`. I think the readability has improved dramatically.

```
#define LOCATION_MAXLEN 50
#define SUFFIX_MAXLEN   5
#define NUMBER_MAXLEN   5
#define TOTAL           2
#define TOTAL_SUBDIR    100
#define PERMISSION      0777

...

char *my_location = "/Users/example/Documents/";
int i, j;
char file_location[TOTAL][TOTAL_SUBDIR][LOCATION_MAXLEN];

char* suffix1 = "AA/",
    * suffix2 = "BB/";

for (i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {

    char temp[LOCATION_MAXLEN+SUFFIX_MAXLEN];
    strcpy_s(temp, my_location);
    strcat_s(temp, i == 0 ? suffix1 : suffix2);

    mkdir(temp, PERMISSION);

    for (j = 0; j < TOTAL_SUBDIR; j++) {
        char subdir_name[NUMBER_MAXLEN];
        sprintf_s(subdir_name, "%d", j);
        int digit_num = strlen(subdir_name);

        strcpy_s(file_location[i][j], temp);
        strcat_s(file_location[i][j], subdir_name);
        strcat_s(file_location[i][j], "/");

        mkdir(file_location[i][j], PERMISSION);
    }
}
```